# SSH client denying connection with error "too many files open"

Tags: linux, ssh-tunneling, sshd, ssh-agent

Running a reverse ssh client on a machine. After some time get a connection denied request, with logs on the ssh client stating

Oct 12 00:21:19 ipaserver0 reverse-tunnel.sh: debug3: channel 1018: waiting for connection

Oct 12 00:21:19 ipaserver0 reverse-tunnel.sh: debug1: channel 1018: connection failed: Connection refused

Oct 12 00:21:19 ipaserver0 reverse-tunnel.sh: socket: Too many open file

Not sure what the issue is here. Is there a limit to the number of channels a ssh tunnel can support.

Comment: How many connections do you create? Maybe check `ulimit -a` and your ssh service in `/proc/<PID>/fd`

Comment: providing the scripts and configuration for this reverse access could help

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on the number of file descriptors a process can open. A ssh tunnel needs a file descriptor for the connection, both on the client and on the server side. Therefor the number of channels is limited.

On Linux, you can use `lsof` to list open files. It will list files of all processes. You can restrict the listed processes with `-c ssh` for the command name or with `-p pid`for a particular process.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same situation.
just notice both server & client side should set open file limit.
if with port forwarding, the forward process also need set it.

### ssh forward process

for example, if host0 run

```
ssh -fNL :1234:host2:1234  host1
```

then you got process

- ssh @host0
  //sudo netstat -ltnp | grep :1234
- sshd @host1
  //sudo netstat -atnp | grep :1234 (run after connect
  //pgrep -af  "sshd: $USER\s*$"

topology:

```
client ----> ssh ===tunnel=== sshd ----> server
```

ssh (-L, -R) forward running in application layer,
each connection need one tcp socket fd.

// and it's low performance for lots of connections.

### for running process

check NOFILE limit:

```bash
$ prlimit -p 1930 -n
RESOURCE DESCRIPTION                 SOFT    HARD UNITS
NOFILE   max number of open files 1048576 1048576 files
```

change NOFILE limit

```bash
prlimit -p 1930 -n1048576
```

### for current interactive bash

check

```
$ ulimit -n
1024
```

change

```bash
ulimit -n 1048576
```